# TextView Android калькулятора

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста каким способом можно сделать подобную разметку, как в Android калькуляторе?
 [image]

То есть чтобы при выполнении действий они были выведены сверху,а их результат автоматически подсчитывался ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошо. Для начала нужно разделить эту разметку на составляющие. Она состоит из двух элементов, причем верхний элемент (который содержит описание действий) представляет собой EditText, а нижний это TextView.
Очевидно что расположенны эти два элемента в контейнере LinearLayout с атрибутом

```
android:orientation = vertical
```

Осталось только сделать так что бы текст был справа. Можно сделать это двумя способами:

- Растянуть EditText и TextView на всю ширину контейнера указав

  ```
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  ```

и сместить текст вправо свойством

```
      android:gravity="right"
```

- Либо просто сместить EditText и TextView вправо

  ```
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ```

и сместить view вправо свойством

```
      android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Вот.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Скажите,а может у Вас есть пример такого android калькулятора?

Comment: Нет, но думаю что то подобное вам поможет [1] (http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmrbool.com%2Fhow-to-create-a-calculator-app-for-android%2F28100&ei=PpdQVfDzOoHSsgHH8YGACg&usg=AFQjCNG4NhC3CSTOYfF5HUvORh968CYiPg&sig2=_YipTm-RG7rC2_kvdfpSbw)

Comment: Спасибо,буду искать на гитхабе